# How to write query for many to one mapped entity in JpaRepository

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities and mapped those using many-to-one annotation but after writing a query for find object using another table id I got an error when I commented out that line and method  called to that application work but I want to implement that functionality and please help me

These are my entity classes:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "Contract")
public class  Contract implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "contractId")
    private long contractId;

    @Column(name="start_date")
    private Date st_date;

    @Column(name="end_date")
    private Date end_date;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "hotel_id", nullable = false)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Hotel hotel;

    // getters and setters
```

Second entity

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="Hotel")
public class Hotel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="hotel_id")
    private long hotel_id;
    @Column(name="hotel_name")
    private String hotel_name;
    @Column(name="hotel_location")
    private String hotel_location;
    @Column(name="hotel_email")
    private String hotel_email;
    @Column(name="hotel_telephone")
    private String hotel_telephone
   // getters and setters
```

My contract service class

```java
@Service
public class ContractService {
    @Autowired
    private ContractRepository contractRepository;

    @Autowired
    private HotelRepository hotelRepository;

    public List<Contract> getAllContracts(){
        return contractRepository.findAll();
    }

    public List<Contract> findByHotelId(Long hotelId,Pageable pageable){
        return contractRepository.findByHotelId(hotelId, pageable);
    }
    public ResponseEntity<?> deleteContract(Long hotelId, Long contractId)                
    {
    return contractRepository.findByIdAndHotelId(contractId,         
    hotelId).map(Contract -> {
        contractRepository.delete(Contract);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Comment not found 
    with ContractId " + contractId + " and hotelId " + hotelId));
}
```

My contract repository

```java
@Repository
public interface ContractRepository extends JpaRepository<Contract, Long> {
    List<Contract> findByHotelId(Long hotelId, Pageable pageable);
    Optional<Contract> findByIdAndHotelId(Long id, Long hotelId);
}
```

I got this error when running my project

> **org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:** Error creating bean with name 'contractController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'contractService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'contractService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'contractRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contractRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.sunTravel.sunRest.repository.ContractRepository.findByHotelId(java.lang.Long,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)! No property id found for type Hotel! Traversed path: Contract.hotel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First Solution**: based on your stack trace, Spring data is looking for id variable (primary key) in your `Hotel` class. So please change `private long hotel_id;` to `private long id;`

**Another solution (no need to change anything just add your own query):**

write your own JPA query using `@Query`.

Example:

```java
@Query("SELECT contract from Contract as contract where contract.hotel.hotel_id = :hotelId")
List<Contract> findByHotelId(Long hotelId, Pageable pageable);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should rename your Primary Key from hotel_id to id then only your repository method will work.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Hotel")
public class Hotel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="hotel_id")
    private long id;
    @Column(name="hotel_name")
    private String hotel_name;
    @Column(name="hotel_location")
    private String hotel_location;
    @Column(name="hotel_email")
    private String hotel_email;
    @Column(name="hotel_telephone")
    private String hotel_telephone
   // getters and setters
```